# mongoose filter query type definition error - Types of property '$where' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

I am a little new to Typescript and I am getting this error with a filter query one `.findOne`

It is saying this:

```
models/User.ts:599:37 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ $and?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $nor?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $or?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $text?: { $search‾ /*                                                                                                   
   *                                                                                                   
   * This is for retrieving data from the database. Pass this filter to queries                        
   * for proper permitteda access.                                                                     
   *                                                                                                   
: string; $language?: string; $caseSensitive?: boolean; $diacriticSensitive?: boolean; }; $where?: string | Function; $comment?: string; _id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<UserType>'.
  Type '{ $and?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $nor?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $or?: FilterQuery<any>[]; $text?: { $search: string; $language?: string; $caseSensitive?: boolean; $diacriticSensitive?: boolean; }; $where?: string | Function; $comment?: string; _id: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ _id?: Condition<string>; password?: Condition<string>; active?: Condition<boolean>; rank?: Condition<RankType>; profile?: Condition<ProfileType>; ... 65 more ...; validateSync?: Condition<...>; }'.
    Types of property '$where' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | Function' is not assignable to type 'Condition<Record<string, unknown>>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<Record<string, unknown>>'.

599     const user = await User.findOne({
                                        ~
600         _id: userId,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
601         ...req.Auth.Filter
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
602     })
    ~~~~~
```

This is my code:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
    _id: userId,
    ...req.Auth.Filter // definitely problem with this line
})
```

The type definition of `req.auth.Filter` is:

```
interface FilterQueryType {
    _id?: {
        $in: string[]
    },
    userId?: {
        $in: string[]
    },
    createdBy?: string,
    createdById?: string,
    awardee?: {
        $in: string[]
    },
    someInvalidFieldToReturnNothing?: string
}
```

Do I need to make my filter type based on mongoose Type definition?

Comment: Why don't you use `FilterQuery<User>` (import from `mongoose`) instead of `FilterQueryType`? If you want to limit to certain fields, use `Pick<FilterQuery<User>, '_id_' | 'userId' | ...>`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to embed your filter criteria inside a `$where` key:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
    _id: userId,
    $where: req.Auth.Filter
});
```

The only top-level keys that are allowed on the argument to `findOne` are

`$and | $nor | $or | $text | $where | $comment | _id`

The `_id` key is only allowed because it's the primary key, so Mongoose provides a shorthand way of selecting an object by it's ID:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
    _id: userId,
})
```

But it's equivalent to:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
    $where: {_id: userId}
})
```

But you can't pass non-unique keys like `awardee` at the top-level, that has to be inside `$where`.

Comment: Hello, using `$where` does not seem to do it the trick for me. I am getting `Type 'FilterQuery<any>' is not assignable to type 'Condition<Record<string, unknown>> & (string | Function)'` on `$where`